# In socialauth plugin Facebook post is not posted getting SocialAuthError

Tags: android, facebook, plugins, facebook-social-plugins

In android socialauth plugin, Facebook post is not posted.
I am getting `SocialAuthError`

```
05-16 19:51:08.989: D/SocialAuthError(19549): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Status not updated. Return Status code :403
    05-16 19:51:08.993: W/System.err(19549): org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError: Message Not Posted
    05-16 19:51:08.993: W/System.err(19549):    at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter$6.run(SocialAuthAdapter.java:868)
    05-16 19:51:08.994: W/System.err(19549):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    05-16 19:51:08.994: D/Share-Bar(19549): Message Not Posted
```